Frictional Torque on a Rotating Triangular Lamina
I was solving this problem, when i came across the issue i am about to ask here,

A uniform right angled triangular lamina is placed on a horizontal floor, which is not friction less. One of the acute angles of the lamina is $\theta$ as shown in the following figure. If $F_A$ and $F_B$ are the minimum forces required to rotate the lamina about stationary vertical axes through the vertices $A$ and $B$ respectively, find the minimum force required to rotate the lamina about a stationary vertical axis through the vertex $C$


I tried solving the problem as follows, consider the following integral $I_1$,
$$I_1 = \int_0^{l\cos\theta}\int_0^{x\tan\theta}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\hspace{1mm}dy\hspace{1mm}dx$$,
then the torque due to friction about $A$ is $\mu rho g I_1$, where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and $\rho$ is the area-mass density thus since to produce maximum torque using minimum force about $A$ we apply $F_A$ at $B$, thus we have,
$$F_A l = \mu \rho g I_1$$
Where $l$ is the length of the hypotenuse of the right angular triangle, doing the same for rotation about $B$ and $C$ we get,
$$F_B l = \mu \rho gI_2 = \mu\rho g\int_0^{l\sin\theta}\int_0^{x\cot\theta}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\hspace{1mm}dy\hspace{1mm}dx$$
$$F_C l\cos\theta = \mu \rho g I_3 = \mu\rho g\int_0^{l\cos\theta}\int_0^{l\sin\theta - x\tan\theta}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\hspace{1mm}dy\hspace{1mm}dx$$
Now obviously it would be really tedious to compute the integrals and relate $F_A$ and $F_B$ with $F_C$ so i tried relating $I_1, I_2, I_3$ but have had no luck yet could anyone please help me find a relation, or suggest and alternate solution to the problem!
Any help would be highly appreicated!

I'm taking an educated guess that this problem is mathematically analogous to calculating centers of mass, area moments of inertia, or something similar.  You can find tables for these integrals in most engineering mechanics textbooks.
